# ehcache replication without manual nor automatic approach

Tags: java, ehcache, distributed

Right now I'm using ehcache in my Java application without any problem. I use it with spring, and it works even if I use it in a distributed environment, using manual approach.

The problem is I have new requirements in my distributed environment: I will add new nodes dynamically, depending on the users, so manual approach won't be an option anymore. I've changed to an automatic approach, and it works fine in development network, but production network doesn't support multicast.

I'm looking for another way to make this work without using manual nor automatic approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to go distributed, you are better off trying [Ehcache with Terracotta clustering](http://terracotta.org/downloads/open-source/catalog), version `4.3.1` of Terracotta with version `2.10.1` of Ehcache.

This way you would get proper clustering, with consistency guarantees that replication can never offer.

The one thing that it requires is at least one server to act as the Terracotta backend.

Note: I am working for Terracotta on Ehcache.